# calling executeFetchRequest in two contexts with same parent

Tags: iphone, core-data, concurrency

Hi I have declared two private contexts with same (NSMainQueueConcurrencyType) parent, one is here:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)childObjectContext{
if (_childObjectContext != nil) {
    return _childObjectContext;
}
_childObjectContext=[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]   initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_childObjectContext setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
return _childObjectContext;
}
```

and second private context:

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)childObjectContext2{
if (_childObjectContext2 != nil) {
    return _childObjectContext2;
}
_childObjectContext2=[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
[_childObjectContext2 setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
return _childObjectContext2;
```

}

and I think problem is with 'executeFetchRequest:error:' because my app freeze on it. I will try simplify my problem. I call performBlock on each context with 'executeFetchRequest:error:'
inside. If each context is assigned to his own thread, why this freeze app? Does it not thread safe?

```
[childObjectContext performBlock:^{
    [childObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request1 error:nil]
}];

[childObjectContext2 performBlock:^{
    [childObjectContext2 executeFetchRequest:request2 error:nil]
}];
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce and your code looks ok. There is something what you haven't told.